# Unable to solve fullPathForFilename: Possible missing file error in cocos2dx

Tags: android, c++, cocos2d-x

I'm currently getting the following error. I'm certain that I have the Mark Felt.ttf file in the Resources -> fonts folder. Currently, I'm developing for android on android-studio.I wonder, what can the problem be? I would love to hear from you!

```
cocos2d: fullPathForFilename: No file found at Mark Felt. Possible missing file.
```

The code

```
auto highscoreLabelHeader = Label::createWithSystemFont("HIGHSCORE", "Mark Felt", 16);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use relative path to you font file, starting from resource folder as root. I.e if you have subfolders, just use `fonts/Mark Felt.ttf`

```
auto label= Label::createWithSystemFont("xyz", "fonts/Mark Felt.ttf", 16);
```

and also make sure `Mark Felt` is systemFont otherwise use

```
auto label= Label::createWithTTF("xyz", "fonts/Mark Felt.ttf", 16)
```

Moreover you can also check this thread

http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/fonts-not-working-on-android-device/7535